# Buggy websites for Selenium testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, functional, web-testing

I am looking for a buggy website to do functional testing with Selenium. The website needs to have some bugs in it. The wider the variety of tests I could do, the better. Could you suggest a buggy website, which I can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Frankly speaking, I tried, learnt & play with automation test scenarios with **amazon.com** as my playground.
2. You can try a bug is fine but important for your learning is you try to automate interaction with multiple different web components. I found amazon is having enough components.
3. If you need few more test websites, have a look [here](https://techbeamers.com/websites-to-practice-selenium-webdriver-online/)

Answer (score 1):

@Narendra Chandratre answer is great, simply exercising the different interactions is a good way to go.

Amazon is a good real website, but if you wish for something more focused, [The Internet](https://github.com/saucelabs/the-internet) is a good resource (you can run it locally or [use this hosted instance](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/)).

It has a long list of situations that cover most of things you will see in a website:

[image]
[image]

I have used it in [my blog post showing some refactoring techniques for automation in testing](http://thatsabug.com/blog/three_exercises_first/).

Answer (score 1):

here are a few websites or applications that you can practice functional testing with Selenium:

1. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) - It is a simple and widely used website, you can practice testing on various elements such as search bar, buttons, links, and others.
2. [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com) - You can practice testing on the shopping cart, product listing, user login, and payment page.
3. [www.flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com) - You can practice testing on the shopping cart, product listing, user login, and payment page.
4. weather.com - You can practice testing on the weather forecasts, search functionality, and weather maps.
5. [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) - You can practice testing on the login page, user profile, and post updates.

These websites are commonly used, widely recognized and have a variety of functionality to practice testing with Selenium.

There are also websites that are developed specifically for people to practice automation testing. Some of the most commonly used ones include:

1. http://automationpractice.com/
2. http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/
3. http://demo.guru99.com/V4/
4. http://newtours.demoaut.com/
5. http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/

These websites offer various functionalities and different types of user interactions that can be automated, allowing users to practice their automation testing skills.